# Flutter ValueListenableBuilder result updates state to show/ hide widget

Tags: flutter, dart, visibility

I am trying to use my ValueListenableBuilder, which generates Yes/ No buttons, to determine whether or not a textformfield will be visible. I.e. user selects the "Yes" button and the state of the app changes to allow the hidden textformfield to be displayed. I am extremely puzzled as to how I can either use setState, NotifyListeners, or ChangeNotifier to accomplish this task.

I am trying to avoid using either a radio button or making buttons outside of the ValueListenableBuilder because my ValueListenableBuilder is designed to generate a lot of my other buttons and I was hoping to incorporate one more function into them. Thanks in advance!

**ValueListenableBuilder**

```
ValueListenableBuilder<Option>(
                  valueListenable: yesNo,
                  builder: (context, option, _) => MakeButtons(
                    num0: 0,
                    num1: 1,
                    makeButtonWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.20,
                    selected: option,
                    onChanged: (newOption) => 
                        yesNo.option = newOption,                                                
                    ifSelected: (newOption) {
                      setState(() {
                        yesNo.option = newOption;
                        yesNo;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
```

**Make Buttons**

```
enum Option {
  option0,
  option1,
}

class MakeButtons extends StatefulWidget {
  MakeButtons({
    this.num0,
    this.num1,
    this.selected,
    this.onChanged,
    this.ifSelected,
    this.makeButtonWidth,
  });
  final int num0;
  final int num1;
  final double makeButtonWidth;
  final Option selected;
  final Function ifSelected;
  final ValueChanged<Option> onChanged;

  @override
  _MakeButtonsState createState() => _MakeButtonsState();
}

class _MakeButtonsState extends State<MakeButtons> {
  List<Widget> makeButtons(int num0, int num1, List<Widget> children,
      List<Color> colors, List<Function> onPresses) {
    List<Widget> buttons = new List();
    for (int i = num0; i < num1; i++) {
      buttons.add(Container(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(
          minWidth: widget.makeButtonWidth,
        ),
        child: RectButton(
            buttonChild: children[i],
            bgColor: colors[i],
            onPress: onPresses[i]),
      ));
    }
    return buttons;
  }

  Option selectedOption;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> children = [
  AutoSizeText(
        'Yes',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, color: Colors.white),
      ),
      AutoSizeText(
        'No',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, color: Colors.white),
      ),
    ];

List<Color> colors = [
      selectedOption == Option.option0
          ? kActiveButtonColor
          : kInactiveButtonColor,
selectedOption == Option.option1
          ? kActiveButtonColor
          : kInactiveButtonColor,
];
List<Function> onPresses = [
      () {
        setState(() {
          selectedOption = Option.option0;
        });
        return widget.onChanged(Option.option0);
      },
      () {
        setState(() {
          selectedOption = Option.option1;
        });
        return widget.onChanged(Option.option1);
      },

return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children:
          makeButtons(widget.num0, widget.num1, children, colors, onPresses),
    );
  }
}
```

**Visibility**

```
visible: yesNo.title == 'A' ||
                yesNo == 'Yes',
            child: InputRow(
              myUnit: defaultUnit,
              inputParameter: 'Units',
              textField: unitController,
              colour: kEmoryDBlue,
            ),
          ),
```